# SQL- performance issue

Tags: sql

I am having performance issues with the following query. It's taking a long time to execute.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1
AS
SELECT /*+ parallel (6) */
(SELECT NVL(MAX(EPKEY),0) FROM EP_FACT)+
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BEGSID ASC, JRN_DT ASC, CP_CLAIM_ID ASC, TYPE_CD_ORDER ASC, TBL DESC) EPKEY,
E.*
FROM TRANSBASE.EP_FACT_STG1 E
WHERE JRN_DT<=(SELECT MAX(JRN_DT)FROM EP_FACT_STG1 WHERE TBL=1)
UNION ALL
SELECT /*+ parallel (6)*/
B.EPKEY,
B.CP_CLAIM_ID,
B.BNFT_CLAIM_ID,
B.LCTN_ID,
B.PRIRTY_IND,
B.END_PRDCT_TYPE_CD,
B.BNFT_CLAIM_DESCP_TXT,
B.JRN_DT,
B.JRN_LCTN_ID,
B.JRN_USER_ID,
B.JRN_STATUS_TYPE_CD,
B.JRN_OBJ_ID,
B.END_PRDCT_CHANGE_DT,
B.USERKEY,
B.TYPE_CD_ORDER,
B.A,
B.BEGSID,
B.TBL,
B.LAST_REFRESH,
1 RECORD_SOURCE_FLAG,
TRANSCAT,
POLYDIM
FROM TRANSBASE.EP_FACT B
WHERE BNFT_CLAIM_ID IN (SELECT BNFT_CLAIM_ID FROM EP_FACT_STG1)
AND END_DT =TO_date('01-JAN-2099 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Dont use subqueries in select and where clause. You can easily convert it to use JOIN

Comment: Please include the execution plan in the question.